# Android NDK: Error: must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am trying to use one big c++ library in my android application. I am using eclipse with android ndk plugin. When I run it, I got this error message;

```
This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard.This
support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or
-std=gnu++11 compiler  options.
```

What should I do? How can I enable this option in eclipse?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add "-std=c++11" to your `CFLAGS` in your `Android.mk`:

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -std=c++11
```

Comment: I added and I got same error mesage. Can you type with full syntax?